# Many to many relationship between nodes Drupal 8

Tags: 8

I am planning to create an app in Drupal 8 that uses a many to many relationship between nodes (Team and Players) where a team has many players and a player can have one or many teams; I am not sure if I need to create a custom table to keep their relationships or to create an entity to do that. In several posts I have seen that entities is the way to go, but since it is only to keep track of the relationship between nodes, it looks like an overkill, since, for the most part, the relationships will be created automatically.
Thank you!

Comment: No need for custom table. If players can use the system, then you can add them as users and add a new content type "Team" with an entity reference field for the players. If the players are just a representation of the relation you mentioned, then also make a new content type "Player" and link the 2 content types together again with an entity reference field; Should you want to do a more advanced architecture and "permission related" things with players in teams take a look at organic groups module https://www.drupal.org/project/og.

Comment: Thank you @seroton for your guidance, I will take a look to the options pointed and  comment to the group the approach used. Have a great day!